# The log-likelihood function of ARMA model after the deprecation of the statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMA

Tags: time-series, statsmodels, log-likelihood

I am following a tutorial building an `AR model` using `ARMA` model from `statsmodels.tsa.arima_model`, I got an error that it has been deprecated, and it is replaced by `ARIMA` from `statsmodels.tsa.arima.model`. I am trying to write a function that calculate a test statistic of the log-likelihood ratio test, which requires the use of the `llf` attribute of an initialized `ARMA` model. I do not know what is the counterpart of `llf` attribute in `ARIMA` model?

I tried `statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA.fit().loglike()` but I did not know what kind of parameter it should get?
`ar_2_model = ARIMA(data, order=(2,0,0) ).fit()`

I tried `ar_2_model.loglike()`, but I could not figure out what kind of parameters to pass to it.

I want to get the value of the log-likelihood function of `ar_2_model` as similar to if I would have used
`ar_3_model = ARMA(data. order=(2,0)).fit()`
`ll_f = ar_3_model.llf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use `llf`:

```
ar_2_model = ARIMA(data, order=(2,0,0) ).fit()
print(ar_2_model.llf)
```